# For $x,y \in \mathbb R$, let $d(x,y) = |x-y|/(1+|x-y|)$. Determine whether $d$ defines a metric on $\mathbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> For $x,y \in \mathbb R$, let $d(x,y) = |x-y|/(1+|x-y|)$.
>
> Determine whether $d$ defines a metric on $\mathbb R$.
>
> If it does, determine whether $\mathbb R$ is compact under $d$.

Since $|x-y|=|y-x|$, $d$ is symmetric.

If $x \ne y$, then $|x-y|>0$, so $d(x,y)>0$.

Since $|x-x|=0$, then $d(x,x)=0$. So, $d(x,y) \ge 0$ with equality if and only if $x=y$.

I am having trouble showing the triangle inequality
$$\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|} \le \frac{|x-z|}{1+|x-z|}+\frac{|z-y|}{1+|z-y|}.$$

Trying a few values, I'm guessing triangle inequality holds.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $d'(x,y)$ is a metric,

$$
d(x,y)=\frac{d'(x,y)}{1+d'(x,y)}
$$

is again a metric. Apply this for $d'(x,y)=|x-y|$.

References:

[Showing $\rho (x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$ is a metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686792/showing-rho-x-y-fracdx-y1dx-y-is-a-metric)

[Showing $d(x,y) = \frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$ is a distance.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104633/showing-dx-y-fracx-y1x-y-is-a-distance?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Proving $d_1=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$ is a metric equivalent with $d$, the Euclidean metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1499091/proving-d-1-fracdx-y1dx-y-is-a-metric-equivalent-with-d-the-eucli)